# Updating a CASL ability in Quasar Vue3 with Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, casl

I'm using Quasar ^2.0.0 and Vue 3.2.22. I'm using "@casl/vue" and "@casl/ability" for permissions. I'm having trouble updating an existing ability. The idea is to be able to update the app's ability based on a user role received after authentication. When I try to use the `update` method to update my rules, I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'm')`

Here's where I'm attempting to make the update (post-authentication).

```
import { AbilityBuilder, Ability } from "@casl/ability";
import { useAbility } from "@casl/vue";

const { update } = useAbility();

function updateAbility() {
  const { rules, can, cannot } = new AbilityBuilder(Ability);

  can(["read", "update", "create", "delete"], "Notes");
  cannot("read", ["Photos", "Videos", "Users", "Files"]);

  update(rules);
}

// Eventually updateAbility will receive a `user` that contains one of several possible roles
onMounted(async () => {
  await onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    ...
    updateAbility();
    ...
  });
});
```

If I comment out the above `updateAbility`, I'm able to successfully use `can` elsewhere in the application based on the configuration in my boot file.

```
import { useAbility } from "@casl/vue";

const { can } = useAbility();
console.log(can("create", "Videos")); // returns false as expected
```

###### casl.js (boot file)

```js
import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import ability from "src/services/ability";
import { abilitiesPlugin } from "@casl/vue";

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability);

  app.config.globalProperties.$ability = ability;
});
```

###### ability.js

```
import { defineAbility } from "@casl/ability";

export default defineAbility((can, cannot) => {
  cannot(["read", "update", "create", "delete"], "Notes");
  can(
    ["read", "update", "create", "delete"],
    ["Photos", "Videos", "Users", "Files"]
  );
});
```

I don't know what's causing this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually to use `createMongoAbility` alongside `AbilityBuilder`. Unfortunately, the documentation for CASL/Vue is a bit out of date. The key concepts I needed to learn were:

1. The `useAbility` composition hook actually returns the full global PureAbility instance, which includes the `can` and `update` methods.
2. The `AbilityBuilder` instance provides a `rules` array that contains all the rule information needed to update the ability.

```
[
    {
        "action": [
            "read",
            "create",
            "update",
            "delete"
        ],
        "subject": "Notes"
    },
    {
        "action": [
            "read",
            "create",
            "update",
            "delete"
        ],
        "subject": "Photos"
    },
    {
        "action": [
            "read",
            "create",
            "update",
            "delete"
        ],
        "subject": "Videos"
    },
    {
        "action": [
            "read",
            "create",
            "update",
            "delete"
        ],
        "subject": "Files"
    }
]
```

3. Calling the `can` or `cannot` methods provided by `AbilityBuilder` automatically updates its `rules` array. You can define any rules you want and simply pass the `rules` array to your global PureAbility instance using its `update` method.

Note: The `can` and `cannot` methods on the `AbilityBuilder` are not the same as the `can` method on the PureAbility instance. This confused me. The former define the rules, and the latter checks them.

```
import { AbilityBuilder, createMongoAbility } from "@casl/ability";
import { useAbility } from "@casl/vue";

const ability = useAbility();

function defineRulesFor(role: string) {
  const { can, cannot, rules } = new AbilityBuilder(createMongoAbility);

  switch (role) {
    case "parent":
      can(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Notes");
      cannot(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Photos");
      cannot(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Videos");
      cannot(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Files");
      break;
    case "teacher":
      can(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Notes");
      can(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Photos");
      can(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Videos");
      can(["read", "create", "update", "delete"], "Files");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return rules;
}

onMounted(async () => {
  await onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {

    // This action returns the authUser object that contains the role
    const authUser = await store.dispatch("users/setAuthUser", user);

    const rules = defineRulesFor(authUser.role);
    ability.update(rules);
  });
});
```